# Azure Table Storage Filter over Partition Key results in Bad Request

Tags: azure

```
var result = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<ImageData>()
                .Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, "12.38"), "AND",
                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, "12.50"))
                    )
                .Take(10)).ToArray();
```

Above filter fails with a bad request. It works if i use either of the combined filters, but the combined filter fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "AND", try `TableOperators.And` (lowercase "and")

Comment: Was just reading the popup in visual studio saying to use AND or OR, good catch.